# Test for consecutive HTML elements in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

I wish to run a test* to check for presence of something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td> name </td> <td> date </td>
</tr>
```

Code, such as  below:

```
assert_select "tr" do
  assert_select "td",  name
  assert_select "td",  date
end
```

looks plausible, but is not correct, as the below for example (which is not the match required) would also pass:

```
<tr>
    <td> name </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> date </td>
</tr>
```

I’m struggling to see how this should be approached from the documentation of [assert_select](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions.html#method-i-assert_select).

Thank you

Daniel

- within a default Rails integration test (I believe this means MiniTest)

Comment: CSS does have a sibling selector which would be `td+td` but it doesn't have selectors based on the text node. Your best bet unless you can add classes or data attributes is probaly to use `assert_select 'td', exp` where `exp` is a regular expression matching the nodes. You could also possible use `css_select` to select the td elements and iterate through them. If it behaves like an enumerable you should be able to use `with_index` to compare with the previous item in the set.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers in the right direction @max. For info, the sibling selector won't return the first td (in this context), only subsequent siblings. css_select returns something of class Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet, which responds to  each_with_index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a regexs on the result of a css_select, which seems a bit inelegant, but worked for my purposes. If there is a better way I'd be interested to hear it. I used something like this:

```
pars = css_select "tr"
regexs = /<td>#{name}<\/td>.*<td>#{date}<\/td>/m
match = false
pars.each { |i| if i.to_s =~ regexs then match = true end}
assert match
```